# SQL Query for last year 30 days in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, I would like to get data for:

1. last 30 days from the current date and
2. also for the last 30 days from the (current date - 365) which is previous year

I was able to do so successfully for the first item:

```
WHERE CREATE_TIMESTAMP > SYSDATE - 30
```

But not sure how to achieve that for the second item. I tried:

```
WHERE CREATE_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN ((SYSDATE - 395) AND (SYSDATE - 365))
```

Moreover, my `CREATE_TIMESTAMP` is a `timestamp` column.

Comment: Why `365`? Why not `366`?

Comment: Yes, for leap year it will be 366 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to get a list of those dates which are within the last 30 days of either this year or the same dates of last year then:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LEVEL + 1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30
UNION ALL
SELECT ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LEVEL + 1, -12 )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30
```

If you are trying to restrict the data from a query to only those dates then:

```
WHERE (  date_column BETWEEN sysdate - 30
                         AND sysdate
      OR date_column BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, -12 ) - 30
                         AND ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, -12 )
      )
```

Or if you are particularly worried about the conversion from `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` in the above filter then you can use the function below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TS_ADD_MONTHS(
  datetime TIMESTAMP,
  months   INT
) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_date CONSTANT DATE := TRUNC( datetime );
BEGIN
  RETURN CAST( ADD_MONTHS( p_date, months ) AS TIMESTAMP )
         + ( datetime - p_date );
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Then in your query can use:

```
WHERE (  date_column BETWEEN SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' DAY
                         AND SYSTIMESTAMP
      OR date_column BETWEEN TS_ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, -12 ) - INTERVAL '30' DAY
                         AND TS_ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, -12 )
      )
```

Comment: Perfect ! More than what I asked for :)  May be because my question was ambiguous. Thanks a lot !